# Do recirculation pumps work with water source heat pumps?

Tags: water, pump, heat-pump

Our plumber has installed the recirculation pump but, when it is on we only have tepid water. When we unplug it we have hot water. Just wondering if recirculation pumps are meant to work with heat pumps and, if so, how? Is there a diagram how to connect it? The cold water seems to be mixing with the hot when the recirculation pump is on.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. You mean that you have a water heater that gets its heat from a heat pump? And, your recirculation pump recirculates the hot water so you don't have to run it for a while before you get hot? (Please edit the answers into your question; thanks.)

Comment: Diagrams and pictures are helpful.